# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Unable to boot - No Bootable device

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot

I have computer that was configured to dual boot Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and Windows 8.

When the computer was rebooted afte shut down the computer fails with following errors

> Checking media = Failed
>
> No Bootable device - Please restart

Before shuting down by mistake I wrote to (dd) /dev/sda thinking it was the SD card drive.

Is there anything that I can do to recovery with out reinstalling everything all over again.

The data was backuped up a few weeks ago.

Any thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

just boot from the livecd and run grub-update on /dev/sda if that's all that's wrong, other wise there isn't much you can do.

Comment: No problem, I was binge answering at the time, that's the reason for the quick reply :p

Comment: I have looked a few Grub tutorial. Do you know of any really basic grub tutorial, or examples that will help me get started on grub?

Comment: overall I like to use grub customizer as it is gui based and offers many methods of customization. google for it, it's possible to install it even while in a livecd environmend, you just need to reinstall it each time. I only use update-grub when my system won't boot, in which case just running sudo update-grub /dev/sda usually fixes it automatically. Please mark the answer as just that if it is that:P